# How to login to Jupyter notebook generated by TensorFlow docker?

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

My docker version

[image]

I run `docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-jupyter`

[image]

log

[image]

```
[I 03:09:11.380 NotebookApp](B Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret

jupyter_http_over_ws extension initialized. Listening on /http_over_websocket

[I 03:09:11.626 NotebookApp](B Serving notebooks from local directory: /tf

[I 03:09:11.626 NotebookApp](B Jupyter Notebook 6.3.0 is running at:

[I 03:09:11.626 NotebookApp](B http://2271c0952dc1:8888/?token=43b3f33c0c9ff0fe3420c21ca3505865e9396dd613412ce7

[I 03:09:11.626 NotebookApp](B or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=43b3f33c0c9ff0fe3420c21ca3505865e9396dd613412ce7

[I 03:09:11.626 NotebookApp](B Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).

[C 03:09:11.632 NotebookApp](B


To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:

file:///root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-1-open.html

Or copy and paste one of these URLs:

http://2271c0952dc1:8888/?token=43b3f33c0c9ff0fe3420c21ca3505865e9396dd613412ce7

or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=43b3f33c0c9ff0fe3420c21ca3505865e9396dd613412ce7

[C 03:13:56.481 NotebookApp](B received signal 15, stopping

[I 03:13:56.483 NotebookApp](B Shutting down 0 kernels

[I 03:13:56.483 NotebookApp](B Shutting down 0 terminals

jupyter_http_over_ws extension initialized. Listening on /http_over_websocket

[I 03:14:01.997 NotebookApp](B Serving notebooks from local directory: /tf

[I 03:14:01.998 NotebookApp](B Jupyter Notebook 6.3.0 is running at:

[I 03:14:01.998 NotebookApp](B http://2271c0952dc1:8888/?token=e52451166ea610fe5559c59eee0f3865e3af25b44c4966d6

[I 03:14:01.998 NotebookApp](B or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=e52451166ea610fe5559c59eee0f3865e3af25b44c4966d6

[I 03:14:01.998 NotebookApp](B Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).

[C 03:14:02.003 NotebookApp](B


To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:

file:///root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-1-open.html

Or copy and paste one of these URLs:

http://2271c0952dc1:8888/?token=e52451166ea610fe5559c59eee0f3865e3af25b44c4966d6

or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=e52451166ea610fe5559c59eee0f3865e3af25b44c4966d6
```

[image]

I enter token `e52451166ea610fe5559c59eee0f3865e3af25b44c4966d6` but cannot login.

Even, when I use command line to set password, it still did not work

[image]

I also enter token then set password, then login, but not success. How to login success?

Comment: Did you Follow the [Tensorflow docker installation documentation to install Tensorflow https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker

Comment: yes. I read it then practice.